# Annotating data in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am attempting at rendering annotated data into my template

My models looks like this

```
class Content(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
body = models.TextField()
reviews_total = models.FloatField(null=True)

def _str_(self):
    return self.title


class Review(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    readability = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    readability_rating = models.IntegerField()
    actionability = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    actionability_rating = models.IntegerField()
    general_comments = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    avg_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And my template looks like this

```
{% for content in content.all %}

 <div onclick="window.location='{% url 'details' 
 content.id %}';">

{{ content.title }}
Reviews: {{ content.review_set.count }}          
Avg Rating: {{ ? }}

{% endfor %}
```

My view looks like this

```
def details(request, content_id):
    content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=content_id)
    return render(request, 'content/details.html', {'content': content})
```

From the following query

```
x = Content.objects.annotate(avg=Avg('review__avg_rating'))
y = vars(x[pk])
y['avg']
```

Which will give me 4.0 for example.

My goal is essentially to to insert y into Avg Rating {{  }}

Is there a way similar to content.review_set.count? Or is it best to do in views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation is added as an attribute to the objects in the `QuerySet`, so you can render this with.

So in your view, you can pass data like:

```
def some_view(request):
    contents = Content.objects.annotate(
        nreviews=Count('review'),
        avg=Avg('review__avg_rating')
    )
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'contents': contents })
```

and in the template, you then render this with:

```
{% for content in contents %}
    Reviews: {{ content.nreviews }}          
    Avg Rating: {{ content.avg }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to show the details of *one* `Content` object, you can render this with:

```
def details(request, content_id):
    content = get_object_or_404(
        Content.objects.annotate(
            nreviews=Count('review'),
            avg=Avg('review__avg_rating')
        ),
        pk=content_id
    )
    return render(request, 'content/details.html', {'content': content})
```

and in the template:

```
{{ content.title }}
Reviews: {{ content.nreviews }}
Avg Rating: {{ content.avg }}
```

so *without* the `{% for content in contents %}` loop.

Comment: Hey Willem. Thanks for your answer. /n
I've tried implementing your suggestion  /n

def details(request, content_id):
    content = get_object_or_404(Content.objects.annotate(
        nreviews=Count('review'),
        avg=Avg('review__avg_rating')),
        pk=content_id)

    return render(request, 'content/details.html', {'content': content})

Is line 2 the problem?

Comment: @JakobL.Tolstrup: in that case, you should not use `{% for content in contents %}`. Can you edit your question and share the view and the (relevant) parts of the template.

Comment: hmm, still no luck

Comment: @JakobL.Tolstrup: I tested this locally with some sample data. So I guess there is still a small difference.